# SDKのwget()関数でファイルのダウンロードが出来ない

Tags: spresense

SDKのwget()関数や、NuttX Shell上のwgetコマンドを使用しても、AWS s3の署名付きURLからのダウンロードが出来ません。
（PCのブラウザからや、MSYS2のwgetからは、ダウンロード出来ます。）
何かほかに設定が必要なものとかありますでしょうか？

- ほか、Googleドライブからのダウンロードも出来ませんでした。
  （https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=ｘｘｘｘｘ）
  ※PCのブラウザからや、MSYS2のwgetからは、ダウンロード出来ます。
- 例えばフリー素材などのページからのダウンロードは出来ました。
  （https://ｘｘｘｘｘ/ｘｘｘ.mp3）

---

「Spresense SDKチュートリアル」記載の、ファイルを保存する手順で実施しました。

> app_wget_cb() 関数を一部変更することにより、ファイルに保存することができます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

お役に立つかわかりませんが、自分の経験上以下の理由が考えられると思います。

1. Host名が長い場合
   これはNuttX8.2の制限でHost名の長さが40になっていることが原因でした。
   Host名が40文字を超えるとwgetが失敗してしまいます。
   `spresense/sdk/apps/include/netutils/webclient.h` に40文字の制約が記載されており、
   以下の定義を
   `#  define CONFIG_WEBCLIENT_MAXHOSTNAME 40`
   以下のように拡張することで文字数を増やすことができます。
   `#  define CONFIG_WEBCLIENT_MAXHOSTNAME 60`
2. TLS証明書が無い場合
   SpresenseではTLS(https)に必要な証明書を`/mnt/spif/CERTS`に書き込んでおく必要があるようで、このディレクトリの中に必要な証明書が無いとダウンロードに失敗するようです。

Comment: ありがとうございました。アクセス制限を外した場合は問題なくダウンロード出来ました。制限時間式の署名付きの場合だけ「AuthorizationQueryParametersError」のエラーが返ってきますが、これはまた別の問題として調べております。

Comment: AuthorizationQueryParametersErrorのエラーは、パラメータが指定されていないような内容のメッセージでした。署名付きURLにはそのパラメータは設定されておりますので、もしかしたらHost名の文字数の他にも、文字数のデファインを変えないといけないとかありますでしょうか？

Comment: CONFIG_WEBCLIENT_MAXFILENAMEの値も増やしたら、ダウンロード出来ました。